# Testing If Person Is Male or Female - If Not Male, Can I Assume It's Female?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I would like to hear from you experts what I should do as a programmer in the following case.

Person is a class that has properties like name, birthday, etc, and one of which is gender that takes either "m" for male or "f" for female. Person class has instance method #male? and #female? to test if gender is "m" or "f", respectively.

The important thing here is that, by design, gender always has "m" or "f" and never becomes nil or any other value.

Now, I often come across the situation where I need to switch logic, depending on which value a given Person instance has in its gender field.

My question then is, is it normal to assume that the gender value is always either "m" or "f", so if it is not "m", then it must be "f", like the following?

```
if (person.male?)
  # do male stuff
else
  # must be female. do female stuff
end
```

OR should I always test to make sure person is female even if it is tested to be non-male like the following?

```
if (person.male?)
  # do male stuff
elsif (person.female?)
  # do female stuff
else
  raise "Person is neither male nor female."
end
```

I feel that the second example is a bit repetitive, and that, more importantly, this if/else clause is not the place for testing the data inconsistency of the model, so I tend to go with the first case, but everytime I do this, I wonder if this is the way it should be. I mean, if this is a boolean field, I would not worry about it, but it's not.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

SAKI

Comment: The second one is more explicit and will not give unexpected results in case a "third sex" is officially recognized. If you are handling only male and female, then either `male?` or `female?` is redundant  (`male?` is false? Then it is female). Anyway, there is no fixed answer here, unless you specify your domain better. In fact, some agencies and web services give an option not to specify sex or handle transexuality. That would break the first form.

Comment: Give this a read: http://www.slideshare.net/cczona/schemas-for-the-real-world-rubyconf-au-201302

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I thought I made my domain clear, though - there are only 2 options BY DESIGN for this field in this app, and that means no matter how many genders there could possibly be in real life, for this app, there are only two options. But I guess you two are suggesting that I (or you would) use the second form despite the redundancy, since it could change in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's simplicity your class to contain only sex:

```
class Person
  def initialize sex
      raise "wrong sex" unless ['m', 'f'].include?(sex)
    @sex=sex
  end
  attr_reader :sex
end

tom   = Person.new 'm'   # ok
anna  = Person.new 'f'   # ok
drwho = Person.new       # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
wrong = Person.new 'cat' # RuntimeError: wrong sex
```

You cannot create `Person` with sex other than `m` or `f` (as you said).

Can you change the `sex`?

```
tom.sex='ff'
# NoMethodError: undefined method `sex=' for #<Person:0x3f32148 @sex="m">
```

Is there other way to change `sex`?

```
tom.instance_variable_set '@sex', 'cat'
# => "cat"
tom.sex
# => "cat"
```

#### To sum up:

> Can I Assume It's Female

It depends on 2 factors:

1. Speed
2. Correctness

If you care about speed, you can avoid it, as you can see I used *hackish* way to change `sex`.
If you must be 100% sure, use that `elsif`.

Comment: Hi Darek, thank you sooo much for your answer and detailed explanation! The sex field, once set, never changes its value because there is no "edit" feature in this app for a reason. Your `tom.instance_variable_set '@sex', 'cat'` example, however, did make me realize that this assumption could be incorrect in some situation. I guess the speed gain (or saving 2 lines) is not major compared to the correctness, so I will use the second form from now on. Thanks again! :)